# Firebase Realtime database query from v8 to v9 SDK

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime database query written using Firebase version 8 that I'm looking to migrate over to the v9 SDK.

```
export const getSingleDataWithQuery = async ({ key, email, criteria }) => {
  if (!criteria) return;
  const snapshot = await realTimeDb
    .ref()
    .child(key)
    .orderByChild(query)
    .equalTo(criteria)
    .get();
  const val = snapshot.val();
  if (val) {
    const keys = Object.keys(val);
    return val[keys[0]];
  }
  return null;
};
```

In this example:

- key would be the '**users**' collection
- the email field is looking for users by their **email**
- and the criteria is the user's **actual email** (jane.doe@gmail.com)

Using Firebase's [Read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) and [Sorting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) documentation I managed to narrow it down to perhaps being this, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
export const getSingleDataWithQuery = async ({ key, query, criteria }) => {
  if (!criteria) return;
  const dbRef = query(ref(realTimeDb, key), orderByChild(email), equalTo(criteria));
  get(dbRef).then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const val = snapshot.val();
      if (val) {
        const keys = Object.keys(val);
        return val[keys[0]];
      }
    }
  });
  return null;
};
```

Comment: I don't see any problem. Did you get any errors? If you're going to use then chaining you won't need the async keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you may have swapped `query` and `email` in the fragments, the only difference is in the way you handle the asynchronous database call and that likely explains the difference. Since you use `then` in the second snippet, the function doesn't actually return a promise and so calling it with `await` it in the caller won't have any effect.

To make those the same again, use `await` in the second snippet too, instead of `then`:

```
export const getSingleDataWithQuery = async ({ key, query, criteria }) => {
  if (!criteria) return;
  const dbRef = query(ref(realTimeDb, key), orderByChild(email), equalTo(criteria));
  const snapshot = await get(dbRef); // 
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    const val = snapshot.val();
    if (val) {
      const keys = Object.keys(val);
      return val[keys[0]];
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```